# Repeat the for loop (animation) until the selected item has the set left value

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I would like the for loop (animation) below to get repeated until the selected item's left value is equal to the **leftLock** variable. Right now, if you click on one of the navigation items, they rotate once (45°) and stop. (It's probably helpful to check the online demo to see it in action.)

**Online demo: http://goo.gl/8rDTr**

I put the `for` loop in another `for` loop and let it run 8 times but when I check the selected items left position by using `console.log($(this).css('left'))`, it always shows me the original left value - it doesn't get updated even though the item has moved to a new position.

I appreciate all help, even if someone can tell me that the implementation of this is way more complicated than I think. :( Unfortunately I couldn't find any solution by reading many other questions posted here and searching on Google.

It's easy to get the item's position after the animation if you slide a box from left to right since one can use jQuery's callback function but when I try to do the same on my example, I get too many values. Thanks!

**Edit1:** I put the animation loop in another loop and checking the selected items current position but its 8 x the same starting value - it doesn't change over the duration of the animation. (new lines are marked bold)

**Edit2:** I think I moved a step forward because I still get 8 x the same value but then, it shows me the new position of the selected item (also 8x) etc. Example:
"79.1333px
79.1333px
79.1333px
79.1333px
79.1333px
79.1333px
79.1333px
79.05px
48px
48px
48px
48px
48px
48px
48px
48px
78.7167px
79.0167px
79.0167px
79.0167px
79.0167px
79.0167px
79.0167px
79.05px"

So I need to somehow filter every 8th value and check the items position by using if else condition. Does it make sense? :P

```
var menu_items = Array("#box_8", "#box_7", "#box_6", "#box_5", "#box_4", "#box_3", "#box_2", "#box_1");
var menuLength = menu_items.length;
var angleDiff  = 360 / menuLength;
var fin = 0;
var leftLock = "260px";
```

$('a.box').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  **for (var a=0; a < 8; a++) {**
    var startAngle = 180 + fin * angleDiff;
    var endAngle = 225 + fin * angleDiff;
    fin++;
    for (var i=0; i < menu_items.length; i++) {
        startAngle += angleDiff;
        endAngle += angleDiff;
        $(menu_items[i]).animate({
            path: new $.path.arc({
            center: [154, 154],
            radius: 106,
            start: startAngle,
            end: endAngle,
            dir: 1
        }),
        opacity: '1'
        },400, animFinished);
    };
    };
function animFinished() {
    console.log($('.selected').css('left'));
}
});

Comment: Not really other than I wanted it to look a bit cleaned up. Here you go: http://www.grafoman.com.tr/temp_menu/index.html - Btw, I'm still after a solution for my problem and do you think that I have to check the element's position by using setTimeout/setInterval?

Comment: leftLock, that's the position of #box_3 yes? you want to loop the animation till this point ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that! I'm still working on it but I'm not able to check the clicked items current position while its beeing animated. For example, I get 8 times the starting position.

Comment: Noone an idea? I'm slowly wondering if there is a bug in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can place a global variable and then when user clicks on the wheel you can count the clicks up t the number which ois the required destination.

Comment: Excuse me if I misunderstood you but do you mean something like: If e.g. the clicked item is #8 (which would require to move 8 times until its at the required destination) make the loop run 8 times?

In case you mean this, it would work but what if the user clicks on another item? I mean the items will have changed positions, so if the user clicks on #7 next, the loop will run 7 times even it needs to run only once because its next to #8.

 - The main problem for my headache seems to be that I animate 8 items simultenously. It would be much easier if it was a box moving from left to right. :)